# some portion of Map disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using `Google map API Version 3` with `jQuery mobile`. I created marker on map then also 1 marker for current position and then I want to print path between two points like current point and some specific spots. For doing this I generated popup with list of fixed spots user can select any and processed after popup application back to map  and tries to plot a route on map but in `Chrome` the map view is destroyed and shown just in corner. Only in `Firefox` no issue arise.

Comment: Do you have any error in console log?

Comment: No error. In firefox working fine but not in chrome.
I just add the event that @Madcoe told in answer then map shows but lost its center in chrome. Firefox remains correct

Comment: Can you add a piece of your code here in order us to see what is wrong with it?

Comment: it is hard to put the code here because there is too much code for that single piece of function. i will try to prepare a small demo code that produce same problem. @Madcoe anyways your answer solve my half problem currently i am debugging my app to sort out the problem then i will update the status Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you load your map inside a hidden element or you change your elements properties after loading a map inside it. If that is the case

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

this might solve your problem.